# zend translate join multiple file languages

Tags: zend-framework, file, translation, multilingual

i am trying to add to my language file, the zend form errors language file, which can be found in

```
ZendFramework-1.11.2.zip\ZendFramework-1.11.2\resources\languages
```

in order to have localized form validators erorrs. This blog http://www.thomasweidner.com/flatpress/2010/03/25/working-with-multiple-translation-sources/comments/ explains what i try to do, but it fails :( it only translates from my .ini file, the .php is not included
Here is what i did:

this is my application.ini

```
resources.translate.adapter = "ini"
resources.translate.default.locale = "it_IT"
resources.translate.default.locale = "en_US"
resources.translate.default.file = APPLICATION_PATH "/lang/source-it.ini"
resources.translate.translation.en = APPLICATION_PATH "/lang/source-en.ini"
;resources.translate.data.directory = APPLICATION_PATH "/lang"
resources.translate.data = APPLICATION_PATH "/lang"
```

and then i have this

```
 <?php
    class Gestionale_Application_Resource_Translate extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract
    {
        public function init ()
        {
            $options = $this->getOptions();
            $adapter = $options['adapter'];
            $defaultTranslation = $options['default']['file'];
            $defaultLocale = $options['default']['locale'];


            $translate = new Zend_Translate($adapter, $defaultTranslation, $defaultLocale);

            $translation_addme = new Zend_Translate(
                'array', 
APPLICATION_PATH."/resources/languages/it/Zend_Validate.php"
                'it',
                array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY)
            );
            $translate->addTranslation($translation_addme);

            foreach ($options['translation'] as $locale => $translation) {
                $translate->addTranslation($translation, $locale);
            }
            Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
            return $translate;
        }
    }
```

and this is my dir

```
c:\www\www\gestionale\application>dir /w /aD
 Il volume nell'unità C è OS
 Numero di serie del volume: 6A5E-FD9B

 Directory di c:\www\www\gestionale\application

[.]           [..]          [.svn]        [configs]     [controllers]
[forms]       [lang]        [layouts]     [models]      [resources]
[views]
               0 File              0 byte
              11 Directory  447.780.282.368 byte disponibili
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you register your  custom resource plugin that you created?

Comment: i don-t get any errors, but the error messages stay in english while the other text gets translated(from the .ini file), it gets auto-included and so i know it works because other text gets translated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just by looking at your code I cannot tell you much. I suspect that your problems might be because you create your own resource plugin, which is unnessesry for this purpose, somethings are not being bootstrap properly, or there are some conflicts with your application.ini. Any way, I will post my translation setup and maybe it will give you some clues.

**application.ini**

Nothing here about translation or locale since I setup them in Bootstrap.php.

**Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initLocale() {
    // define locale
    $locale = new Zend_Locale('en');

    // register it so that it can be used all over the website
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);
}

protected function _initTranslate() {
    // Get Locale
    $locale = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale');


    // Set up and load the translations (there are my custom translations for my app)
    $translate = new Zend_Translate(
                    array(
                        'adapter' => 'array',
                        'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/languages/' . $locale . '.php',
                        'locale' => $locale)
    );

    // Set up ZF's translations for validation messages.
    $translate_msg = new Zend_Translate(
                    array(
                        'adapter' => 'array',
                        'content' => APPLICATION_PATH .
                        '/resources/languages/' . $locale . '/Zend_Validate.php',
                        'locale' => $locale)
    );

    // Add translation of validation messages
    $translate->addTranslation($translate_msg);

    Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);

    // Save it for later
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
}
```

Comment: ehm that gives me the same result, some get translated some don't, in particular i have problem with this string not being translated "    * A record matching '123' was found"

Comment: i found the error somebody at zend forgot to add '', like this     "A record matching '%value%' was found" => "E' già stata trovata una riga con valore %value%",
 instead before it was like this     "A record matching %value%  was found" => "E' già stata trovata una riga con valore %value%",

Comment: @max4ever. Happy to hear that you found out what the problem was.

Comment: should the cache set to both translate objects or just to the main one?